# Converting Google sheet Cell text value to a floating point value

Tags: google-sheets, localization, spreadsheet, number-formatting, substitution

I am using Google spreadsheet from google docs online. I have a text like 1.12345 in Cell C7, and I want to convert it into floating point value for using in below formula. The rest of the cells already contain whole numbers

```
C5 * C6 / C8 * value(C7)
```

Here, I am probably using the wrong function as value is not working, I am getting error saying that - VALUE parameter '1.12345' cannot be parsed to a number.

Which function should be used here for converting C7 cell value to a floating point value.
Thanks,

Comment: If you replace the "." with ",", does it work?

Comment: Yes replacing with "," does work, but I also have a "," in my final result. I think I should have "."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this:

```
=C5 * C6 / C8 * SUBSTITUTE(C7; "."; ",")
```

Comment: It works, and now I don't have any error. However, now I have a comma (",") in my final result. If I am substituting all the values in my formula:  100000 * 1 / 100 * substitute((1.12345;".",",") The result is 1123,45. I think the result should be 1123.45

Comment: @XMarshall try: `=SUBSTITUTE(C5 * C6 / C8 * SUBSTITUTE(C7; "."; ","); ","; ".")`

Comment: Thanks its working now. So we need to substitute the final result also